# Android studio emulator start without response

Tags: android-emulator, android-device-manager

So I am new to android developer, the AS start first for the default 6.0sdk, emilator runs well but after I download the 4.0.3sdk and the exact emulator, the emulator crashed while starting, the emulator screen keep black without response. what is the problem?thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem,for I delete

- C:\Users\chcc.android

and redownload the sdk and Emulator,it runs!